How to get coordinates of centers of edges in godot?
I want to know that how to get coordinates of edge centers(like bottomCenter, topcenter etc) in godot.

Please elaborate. The center of edges of what do you want to get?

I want ask, that while spawning/generating another scene(like summoning a tree(sprite) on top of stump(sprite)), the tree spawns at the mid of stump but I want tree to summon at the bottom corner of stump(rectangle around stump sprite). I've achieved it by adding/subtracting certain values from coordinates. But I want to know whether there is a specific method/function to do so, like how we do so in pygame using rectangles.By the way, I'm using Godot 3.6.

It's hard to answer the question without more detail.
In the case that you literally just want the positions of the edge, you can add half the width. to the position. If you provide code, you'll get a more useful answer.
right_center = sprite.global_position + new Vector2(sprite.sprite.texture.get_width(), 0)
top_center = sprite.global_position + new Vector2(0, sprite.sprite.texture.get_height())

This is not exactly what you asked, but you could also consider modifying the Offset Property of Sprite. This changes the draw position of that sprite.
Similarly, you can check centered to false, which behave similarly.
For example, I'm assuming you have a node representing a tree stump, and when you add a sprite at that stump's position, it puts the center of the sprite at the location of the tree stump node, possibly clipping through the ground.
(note: screenshots Godot 4, but the docs I linked above are Godot 3.5)

You can add an offset to the stump, it can still be positioned along the floor, but be drawn above it.


Godot does not have this out of the box.
Figuring out the boundaries is different depending on the type of Node (i.e. Control vs Node2D vs Spatial).
In your case, being a Sprite, we are tallking about a Node2D. Unlike Controls, Node2Ds do not have an inherent size.
However, the visual size of Sprite is given by its texture... So you could get the size of the texture of the Sprite and use that to compute the position you want.

However, given your use case, I'm going to suggest something different...
For the spawn point add a child Position2D to your scene so you can place it visually on the editor on the position you want.
Then from your code get a reference to the Position2D, read its position (or global_position depending on your spawn code), and use it to place your spawned objects.
If you were, for example, to make a weapon that shoots projectiles, you would want them to appear from the tip of the weapon, which would depend on the sprite, and not necesarily be at a corner or edge center. In that case using a Position2D that can be positioned visually and without messing with the code will give you a better workflow.

Thanks, this also a good solution for my problem.
